# arm-linux-gcc vs arm-elf-gcc

Tags: embedded, arm, gnu-toolchain, uclinux

I am looking at uClinux system that builds the kernel with arm-linux-xxx, but builds the user apps with arm-elf-xxx.

If the apps are intended to run on linux, wouldn't it be better to build everything with arm-linux-xxx ?

Where does one set that option in the overall uClinux build config?

Comment: Are arm-linux-* and arm-elf-* symbolic links to other applications? For example, on my system, arm-linux-gcc points to arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-gcc.

Answer (score 2):

The names of the compilers don't necessarily mean anything. Depending on who built the compilers (and named them), you'll get differing results. Arguably, there is a correct name for a particular configuration, but some random compiled gcc may not be correct.

For the CodeSourcery compilers (likely the most correct names), see [their platforms page](http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/platforms.html) for what their naming means.

Answer (score 2):

You can run `arm-linux-gcc -v` and `arm-elf-gcc -v` to see some differences between these two versions of gcc (such as target architectures/languages).

Answer (score 0):

ELF is the binary format [linux and many others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) use:

> The ELF format has replaced older
>   executable formats such as a.out and
>   COFF in many Unix-like operating
>   systems such as Linux, Solaris, IRIX,
>   FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, DragonFly
>   BSD, Syllable, and HP-UX (except for
>   32-bit PA-RISC programs which continue
>   to use SOM). ELF has also seen some
>   adoption in non-Unix operating
>   systems, such as the Itanium version
>   of OpenVMS, and BeOS Revision 4 and
>   later for x86 based computers (where
>   it replaced the Portable Executable
>   format; the PowerPC version stayed
>   with Preferred Executable Format). The
>   PlayStation Portable, PlayStation 2,
>   PlayStation 3, Wii and GP2X consoles
>   also use ELF. AmigaOS 4 and MorphOS
>   also running on PowerPC machines, use
>   ELF. On the Amiga platform the ELF
>   executable has replaced the previous
>   EHF (Extended Hunk Format) which was
>   used on Amigas equipped with PPC
>   processor expansion cards. The Symbian
>   OS v9 uses E32Image[3] format that is
>   based on ELF file format.
>
> Most Sony Ericsson (for example, the
>   W800i, W610, K790, etc.), some Siemens
>   (SGOLD and SGOLD2 platforms: from
>   Siemens C65 to S75 and BenQ-Siemens
>   E71/EL71) and Motorola (for example,
>   the E398, SLVR L7, v360, v3i and all
>   phone LTE2 which has the patch apply)
>   phones can run ELF files through the
>   use of a patch that adds assembly code
>   to the main firmware (Known as the
>   ELFPack, in the underground modding
>   culture).

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember at some point that that bit in the middle didnt matter.  As already mentioned elf is the standard file format, you want to use that anyway and will get that anyway independent of the binary name.  What may (or not) matter more is the calling convention, I dont know if when calling a shared library function you have to get your calling convention to match or if it is handled for you somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the linked output from the arm-elf-xxx toolchain is a linux loadable binary, while arm-linux-xxx outputs a kernel object (ko), which is a blob with its own linkage format (for modules), or the main kernel itself, which doesn't need a packaging format.  I.e., for user space you want the final dynamically linked object to be an ELF executable, library, or shared object.  For kernel space, you want the final object (kernel or module) to be in the linux-arm-kernel linkage format.

You'll notice that the intermediate objects (.o files) of both targets are probably all ELF, since that is what the toolchain is expecting.

Comment: That's pretty much wrong. There is no difference in toolchain (or there doesn't *need* to be one) for kernel and userspace builds.

Answer (score 0):

In our case we build linux using sparc-elf-gcc and we build busybox(appliation run on linux) using sparc-..-linux-gcc. and I think this is correct, not the other way around.